# Where and how best to call the first initial server-side external API query in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I wanted to ask a question to clarify some points of the process of developing web applications in Nuxt 3 using the compositon api. I'm developing an application whose content depends on the user's location. Therefore, when the user first accesses the site, I must first determine the user's IP address using the external API of a special service, and then using the received user's IP Address, I must determine the user's city with another external API service in order to then receive content from my API service using the received user's city by its IP address. I wanted to clarify where it is better to make requests with the definition of the IP address and city of the user so that everything works optimally and is correctly implemented logically.

I use [Ipify](https://api.ipify.org) API service to detect user IP Address

I use [Dadata](https://dadata.ru) API service to detect user location by user IP Address

Answer (score 0):

You can make a [plugin](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins) and have it hooked into an event and then setup everything. [More on which hooks are available](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/hooks)

```
// plugins/setup.ts
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {

    nuxtApp.hook('app:created', () => {
        Log.info('App created');
    });
    nuxtApp.hook('app:mounted', () => {
        Log.info('App mounted');
    });
});
```

An alternative is that you write everything in the `layouts/default.vue` to set everything up in an `onMounted` hook, but I find this a bit hacky as you ideally want to separate UI from business logic